# Remove Unnecessary Fields from Contact and from Activities

Tags: contacts, joomla, activities

There are areas where an Individual record is opened or used in the Activities. I think there should be an option for their removal.

For example when creating individual records; We have not used the current Employer, Task Title, Nickname, Phone Location, Phone Type, Contact Source and External ID options for 6 years. But it's on the screen. I think they have to be hidden in some way.

In the same way activity records; I don't use fields like Location, Transaction Status, Priority. These sometimes cause incorrect entries and there are no menus to hide.

Is there any development or solution proposal?

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/uploads/0157eea8b229b838a40d705febf77683/-001277.png

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/uploads/778c239a93ab572ac2ed1455af8738c6/-001276.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Work is underway on a [Form Builder](https://github.com/totten/afform) that will allow folks to hide fields as needed.

For now, you can hide fields with jQuery, ideally loaded through an extension.  However, some of the fields you mark are required and so their values would need to be set even if hidden.

Comment: I couldn't find the related plugin in CiviCRM Extensions. Could you give us a source about the installation. I don't want to make mistakes and I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to pass a sample solution;

When I uninstall the following section from

```
administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Activity/Form/Activity.php
```

`'location' => array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => ts('Location'),
        'attributes' => CRM_Core_DAO::getAttribute('CRM_Activity_DAO_Activity', 'location'),
        'required' => FALSE,
      ),`

it leaves the form. So there is no need for such serious teferruata. But a permanent operation can be done to prevent any updates from becoming obsolete. Could you support this?